# MySQL: Sum if rows are equal

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 4 columns: `Client` , `thickness` , `material` and `amount`.

I want to make a SQL select-query to select everything, but when the client, thickness and material are the same their value of 'amount' should be added.

How would I go about creating such a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straightforward (a simple `GROUP BY`):

```
SELECT Client, thickness, material, SUM(amount) as amount
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Client, thickness, material;
```

Change your_table for the name of your table. If only 1 row exists of one combination of Client, thickness and material, it will select it as is.

Check the [`GROUP BY` MySQL page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html) for more information.